# Middle Mouse Button View control

Tags: interface, 3d-view, osx

How can I activate control of view with middle button (wheel)? Middle button (scroll wheel) on mouse zooms only. Depressing wheel brings Dashboard (OSX 10.6), not control of view?

Comment: Sounds like OSX is catching the keypress before it reaches blender. Is it possible you could rebind or disable the dashboard? If not, you can change what button blender uses or use the *emulate 3 button mouse* option which allows you navigate the view with `Alt+LMB`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to disable the shortcut for the dashboard in your system settings.
To do so, open your settings, go to keyboard, shortcuts, mission control. 
There you will find a shortcut for dashboard, which you then have to change to something else, so OS X isn't faster than blender using this shortcut.